# Javascript dynamic variable name

Tags: php, javascript, metaprogramming

I need something like this.

```
var thing_<?php echo $php_var->n ?> = <?php echo '32' ?>
```

want to create something like this :

```
var thing_342 = '32'
```

Comment: What's the question? And why do you need something like that anyway? `thing['342']` would usually be saner.

Comment: It looks like you solved your own problem... Could you elaborate a bit more on what you're going for here?

Comment: No, you don't need this misfeature. Period.

Comment: You should definitely mention your overall *goal* here.  What you are trying to do is 99% likely to be the wrong way to achieve your goal.

Comment: ..and possibly subject to JS code injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an object, and use it as an associative array/hash/whatever you are used to call it.

```
var thing = {};
thing[342] = '32';
```

or

```
var thing = {342: '32'};
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `$php_var->n = 342`

```
var data = <?php echo $php_var->n ?>;
eval("var thing_" + data + "=32;");
alert(thing_342); // output 32
```

Simple example:

```
var data = 342;
eval("var thing_" + data + "=32;");
alert(thing_342); // output 32
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var container;
var var_name='lolo';
container[var_name]='he he he';
alert(container.lolo);
```

not exactly what you want, but I guess it is close enough.